# Does if(this) {} else {} ever visit the else in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, this

Is there any case where the condition `if(this) {}` fails? Because I couldn't think of a scenario where `this` is undefined.
This is not an important question nor something anyone would normally use, I'm just asking out of pure curiosity.

Comment: `if (undefined)` is the same as `if (false)`. No error will result, if that's what you mean by "fail".

Comment: Note that this is something you could have tested in your browser console in less  time than it took to type in the question.

Comment: please edit your title. No one would ever search for this title in the future, defeating any potential benefit to the larger community.

Comment: `this` can be `undefined` in some cases. Like inside an arrow function, for example.

Comment: `(function () { "use strict"; return this === void 0; })()`

Comment: `this` can also be a primitive (other than `undefined`): `"use strict"; (function(){ if(this){ console.log("Truthy"); } else { console.log("Falsy"); } }).call(false);` logs `"Falsy"`. Even without strict mode, [falsy objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/all) are possible: `(function(){ if(this){ console.log("Truthy"); } else { console.log("Falsy"); } }).call(document.all);` logs `"Falsy"` in modern browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in some execution contexts, `this` is `undefined`, which is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in JavaScript:

> In strict mode, however, if the value of this is not set when entering an execution context, it remains as undefined, as shown in the following example:

Here is at least one convoluted scenario in which the following conditions must be met:

- global or function execution in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)
- the function was defined at the top-level (effectively being a function of `window`)
- that function was called directly without invoking its parent (i.e. `foo()` and not `window.foo()`)
- the function returned `this`

```
function foo() {
  'use strict'; // see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode
  return this;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this